# Java Error "cannot find symbol - variable"

Tags: java, scope, compiler-errors

Beginner coder here. I have looked everywhere for help with this, but I seem to be missing something. I declared the variable, and I have checked the scope. Can anyone offer some assistance?

```
public class ValidateFloat
{
private String validFloat;

public boolean ValidateFloat(String str)
{
    validFloat = str;

    for(int i = 0; i < validFloat.length(); i++)
    {
        char letter = validFloat.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isDigit(letter) == false)
        {
            ....
        }
        else if (Character.letter.compareTo(e) != 0 || Character.letter.compareTo(E) != 0
                 || Character.letter.compareTo('-') != 0)
        {
            ....
        }
    }
}
}
```

The error is at all instances of Character.letter.compareTo. Error - cannot find symbol - variable letter.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It means that in the Character class of java, there is no variable called letter. So the moment it reads `Character.letter` it becomes unable to find any static variable called `letter` that you are referencing

Comment: Why did you write `Character.letter`?  The variable is just called `letter`.  I think you were trying to cast it, which would be `((Character) letter)`.

Comment: So you want to check if the `letter` is 'E' or 'e' , right?

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder When I tried just "letter.compareTo" - without the "Character" in front of it - I got the error "char cannot be dereferenced". Do you know how I would go about fixing that?

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder yes, the goal is to check to see if it equals 'E', 'e' or '-'

Comment: Just type `if(letter != 'e' && letter != 'E' && letter != '-'`

Comment: Have you considered writing `if (letter == 'E' || letter == 'e' || letter == '-')` at all?

Comment: I can't believe I didn't consider either of those options... I would over complicate something that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this link could inform you how to use [compareTo() method](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-compareto)
which is used only for `Strings`.

What you wish to do is check if the character `letter` is not equal to 'e', not equal to 'E' and not equal to '-'. So you use this:

```
if(letter != 'e' && letter != 'E' && letter != '-')
{
    .....
}
```

This executes your statements only if the letter is **none** of the above.